# How to trim the path?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I can get the path using the following code,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

and the output is like this

```
~Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<IOSVERSION>/Applications/<UUID>/Documents/My folders
```

But i want to trim the path, like, i want to get the path as /Documents/My folders. How it can be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use string manipulation to accomplish this. If you just want the last 2 path components you can use `lastPathComponent` and `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` to get and remove path components and use `stringByAppendingPathComponent` to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

why did you want to trim the path
try this

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, NO);
```

This gives you output like this `~/Documents`